# Dúvida em exercício com regra de 3

Tags: c

estou fazendo uma lista de exercícios e num deles eu preciso calcular a inflação de duas mercadorias de um mês para outro. 
Consegui fazer o exercício para quando a inflação é <= 100%, mas e se for maior... alguma ideia do que eu deveria fazer? 
Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  float valorMarco1, valorMarco2, valorAbril1, valorAbril2, infl1, infl2, x1, x2;

  printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 1 em 01/março: ");
  scanf("%f", &valorMarco1);

  printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 2 em 01/abril: ");
  scanf("%f", &valorAbril1);

  printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 2 em 01/março: ");
  scanf("%f", &valorMarco2);

  printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 2 em 01/abril: ");
  scanf("%f", &valorAbril2);

  x1 = (valorAbril1 * 100)/valorMarco1;
  infl1 = x1 - 100;

  x2 = (valorAbril2*100)/valorMarco2;
  infl2 = x2 - 100;

  printf("A inflação da mercadoria 1 teve o percentual de: %.1f \n", infl1);
  printf("A inflação da mercadoria 2 teve o percentual de: %.1f", infl2);
}
```

Desculpem qualquer coisa, sou iniciante.

Comment: No caso parece ser um problema de matemática, não de C. Como já respondeu, fechei aqui para fins de organização, mas você pode marcar a sua própria resposta assim o post fica como resolvido.

Comment: Tudo bem. Eu só posso marcar minha resposta como certa daqui 6 horas. Se eu conseguisse mudar a categoria da minha pergunta eu mudaria, mas não sei se tenho mais opção de edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, consegui fazer com ajuda desse site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070438/getting-percentage-difference-between-two-numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
float valorMarco1, valorMarco2, valorAbril1, valorAbril2, infl1, infl2;

    printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 1 em 01/março: ");
    scanf("%f", &valorMarco1);

    printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 2 em 01/abril: ");
    scanf("%f", &valorAbril1);


    printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 2 em 01/março: ");
    scanf("%f", &valorMarco2);

    printf("Insira o valor da mercadoria 2 em 01/abril: ");
    scanf("%f", &valorAbril2);


    infl1 = ((valorAbril1 - valorMarco1)/valorMarco1)*100;
    infl2 = ((valorAbril2 - valorMarco2)/valorMarco2)*100;

    printf("A inflação da mercadoria 1 teve o percentual de: %.2f \n", infl1);
     printf("A inflação da mercadoria 2 teve o percentual de: %.2f \n", infl2);
}
```

Mas fiz assim primeiro, pra ficar mais passo a passo

```
div1 = valorAbril1/valorMarco1;
    mult1 = div1*100;
    infl1 = mult1 - 100;
```